# How to receive Multipart data in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am sending data from android app to my nodejs web server using retrofit2 lib
I am sending field data with one image

Android code

```
@Multipart
    @POST("u_post_i")
    Call<RxtraPostApi> post_with_img(
            @Part("Pid") RequestBody Pid,
            @Part("supportPid") RequestBody supportPid,
            @Part("msg") RequestBody msg,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part filePart);
```

This is my nodejs code

```
export function user_img_rec(req,res): Promise<hs_coman_return_obj> {
    try {
        console.log('A1: ', req.name.msg); // Getting error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined)
       console.log('A3: ', req.body.msg); // Getting error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined)
        console.log(req.body.toString('utf8')); //Getting With this kind of forment
```

**

> ```
> --43441257-300c-4bd4-b4ca-af1b1cafb6c7
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="msg"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 5
>
> Hhhhh**
> ```

```
    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(null);
    }
}
```

Is there anyone who knows how to read both property and image in nodejs

Comment: _Content-Type_ for the streaming data should be **"application/octet-stream"**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multer for that--> https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Multer takes req and req and adds file(or files) property in req object.
So you can read a file in req.file(req.files).

Multer uploads the file first and then set file (or files) property. So in case, you don't want to store file you have to unlink file from file-system.